# Finding the frequency of digits in a vector using R

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers

```
a = c(1:100)

digits = c(0:9)
```

I want to know the frequency of digits in the vector. I want the output precisely as the below example:

```
Digits   Frequency  
0        10  
1        20  
2        20  
3        20  
4        20  
5        20  
6        20  
7        20  
8        20  
9        20
```

How to get this output using R?

Comment: Are you thinking of a histogram?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the numbers to character with `as.character` then split to individual characters with `strsplit` and count the frequency with `table`.

```
table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(a), "")))
# 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
#11 21 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

Or in case for more variations of input:

```
table(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", format(a, scientific =FALSE)), "")))
# 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
#11 21 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

Comment: Just be careful if you have non-integer numbers, since depending on the formatting, the result of this can change a lot (e.g. as.character(0.000001) gives `"1e-06"` by default or `"0.000001"` if `options(scipen=9)` is set). While this answer is good for integer data or our own scripts, I would avoid using it in R packages or scripts meant to be distributed to third parties for that reason.

Comment: @zeehio Hope it works now also for non-integer and also for characters.